# What to ask before the end of probationary period?

Tags: interviewing, colleagues, employer-relations, leadership, probation

There is many of example questions for job interview. But what I, as a team lead, should ask before the end of the staff member's probationary period?

Comment: What do you want to know/get out of your team member?

Comment: I need to make this interview :) His or her skills I know, but this interview is place, where I should make second impression if he or she is still not determined why to be a member of our team. I want some topic tips, for example about feedback to me, how he/she likes work environment, collegues... Do not put pressure on him, but on other side still to express interest

Comment: Does your place actually interview people to see if they pass probation? That seems ... unusual.

Comment: no @OmarL, not usually, but this employee probation will end before my christmass vacation. I just want to ensure, if I can count with him on january, how to redistribute work and so on. Or just say thank you, and good luck if we will not see each other on January. I will make meet like this with other members too, but these will be ordinary 1-to-1 meet. They are not in probation. So meet with this one member is little bit different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask for *their* feedback, but a week or two *before* the end of the probation period.

There will be three cases:

- No feedback or irrelevant feedback. This is generally fine, although for some positions you may want a candidate that is able to provide helpful analysis/critique, so no that might be a *slight* negative point for your final evaluation.
- Helpful feedback: Congratulations, you just found something you can improve in your organization. Also you found a member of your team that you might want to ask for feedback more often, since their feedback proved to be helpful.
- Devastating or even hateful feedback. This only happens rarely, but if it happens it is important: Check if the feedback is true (maybe manager X really has a habit of groping new employees, maybe the HR-Department is indeed taking bribes). If you can be sure the feedback does not correlate to reality, you just found that this employee may have a serious psychological problem that may pose a problem in the future.

The last case happens only very rarely, but there *are* people who do their job well but have some paranoid or warped perception of reality. I once had a coworker who felt lied to and mistreated by everyone and ended up threatening my boss's kids and mother at their personal home.

Before asking for feedback, make it clear that the decision about employment will be not done on the same date. So in the case of unusual feedback, you have some time to discuss with your boss/HR/whoever.

But if it is already very clear that you will not continue to employ an employee, communicate it early. People do have to do arrangements, like terminating their living-arrangements, which may have long notice-periods. You do not want to force someone to pay three extra months for a flat they will not need anymore.
Some will say that telling early is a danger for the company - that a employee should be escorted out of the building as soon as they learn that they have been fired. I guess that mostly depends on working-culture and if your employees (even fired ones) feel like they are being treated with respect and fairness.

Ask for feedback even then, ideally a bit after. Their feedback might be a bit "raw", but sometimes more truthful and therefor more helpful.

Comment: I honestly think the chance of getting any real feedback from an employee before you've confirmed they've passed probation is pretty small.

Comment: I don't think, @PhilipKendall. If I would in position of employee, and there are some blockers why I don't want to continue, this interview is realy good place where to say it. And offten the last one opportunity to say it to teamleader, not to HR

Comment: If I were the employee, I would avoid saying anything that could be used against me.  The last week of probation is also the last opportunity for the employer to fire me without giving the full notice period for permanent employees, as in the contract .

Answer (score 7):

If you have no serious concerns about the staff member and just have to do this to ensure a box is ticked on a system somewhere, make this the entire content of the interview:

> Congratulations, you've passed your probation. Unless you've got anything you want to raise now, let's all go and do some work.

Anything else you should be discussing in your regular 1-to-1 meetings.